# How many *EDIT* votes I still have today?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When reviewing the [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day), there's now limit of 40 edit votes, then it displays:

> Out of votes - you may only vote 40 times a day

#### Is there an easy way to find out how many EDIT votes I still have left today?

Or, how many edit votes I already casted today.

Comment: The only way I know is the *reviews* filter of the *activity* tab in the user profile page. According to [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/684229/tomas?tab=activity&sort=reviews) you used all 50 votes yesterday. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

In other words, no, you don't get a warning, and there isn't any page available that tells you how many votes you have left.

Comment: Odd counts...do you use 36-bit words at work?

Comment: Really, looks like they use base-6 number system :)

Comment: I have [six fingers on my left hand.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093779/) :)