# Can you provide a notice of how many edit votes I have remaining?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I know we get a total of 50 votes for suggested edits.  It would be really really nice, if we had some sort of notification as to how many votes we have left for the day.

This request is different from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127864/how-many-edit-votes-i-still-have-today) because I am asking for some sort of notice to see how many we have yet.

Something like this:

[image]

Or as @BenBrocka suggested:

[image]

Can this be done?

Comment: IMO a simple "5 votes remaining" or something like we do with up/downvotes would be more helpful so it's not always there, just when needed

Comment: @BenBrocka I agree, I just threw that up there as a sample.  Having something as an indicator I think is better than nothing, especially when there are times there are big back-logs of edits to review

Comment: @BenBrocka updated with new suggestion.

Comment: I think @Ben meant that you just get the "5 votes remaining" notification *when you vote* (which is how it works with normal up / down votes).  That way you don't see the running count all the time, but you are notified when you're running low.

Comment: @jadarnel27 or that too. :)